# How to remove divider from actionbar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I am integrating custom view for actionbar. However, I'm not able to remove divider of actionbar. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

I apply theme in manifest like this:

```
<application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        ...
```

Inside `themes.xml` I have:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/mytheme_primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/mytheme_secondary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/mytheme_tertiary</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    </style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
            <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
            <item name="android:ratingBarStyle">@style/RatingBarAppTheme</item>
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
            <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        </style>

        <!-- ActionBar styles -->
        <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_action_bar</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
        </style>
```

Although I'm setting actionbar divider to be transparent from two parts but seems it doesn't take effect anyway :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem before.
Set windowContentOverlay to null will make it has no divider.

In your style xml file, put this:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

and become

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:ratingBarStyle">@style/RatingBarAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks azwar, it doesn't work when last two lines are inside `MyActionBar` However works fine when they are in `AppTheme`. Please update your answer then I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Good answer. Works for me

Answer (score 0):

You should add `actionbarDivider` to your main `Theme`:

```
<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
```

Comment: `AppBaseTheme`- who is the `parent`?. Also did you add `<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>` to `AppBaseTheme`? i add the same issue and solved it with that solution (and by moving to `Toolbar` which is much better

Answer (score 0):

**Just add in Activity**

```
supportActionBar!!.elevation = 0F
```

Example:

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

        supportActionBar!!.elevation = 0F //add this line
```